# Drupal reset password token

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, token, reset-password

i neeed to know if during reset password process, Drupal stores token for one time login somewhere in db, or eventually how can i track login link generation in db.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hash is regenerated so it update users table , so no available trace. You use some hook to apply log trace on this action to get store it in other table or file but it's not recommanded

Comment: how it updates user table? is there a way to recognize when a reset-password is requested?